# How to use react-tether with react-dom createPortal to be able to style tethered component according to the component it's tethered to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a Component in which I render some buttons. Each button should have its tooltip. I'd like to make tooltip appear when I :hover button. But because my tooltip can contain not only text, I cannot use things like balloon or create it only with css.

The idea is to use react-tether to tether my own Tooltip component to the button. But then I have to manage that if I hover the button, the tooltip appears. So I want to use react-portal to move the tooltip inside of my button component so I'd be able to style the tooltip according to its actual parent.

This is the idea I already came up with, but it doesn't work as it is.

```
    export const Bar: React.StatelessComponent<IBarProps> = (props) => {
    const { button1, button2} = props;

      return (
        <div>
          <TetherComponent
          ...
          >
            <Button
             ref={button1ref} //???
             ...(some props)
            >
              {button1.text}
            </Button>
            {
              createPortal(
                  <tooltip>button1.tooltipText</tooltip>,
                  button1ref)
            }
          </TetherComponent>

          <TetherComponent
          ...
          >...the same with second button
          </TetherComponent>
        </div>
    )}
```

where Tooltip is just React.StatelessComponent and Button is simple React.PureComponent.

I get usually stuck at the problem, that Button is JSX.Element and not Element so I cannot use it as a targeted element in the portal. Another thing is, that I am not sure about how to use ref in this case and if it's not better to use id.
I'm open to any idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think this peace of code I wrote will help you. 
It doesn't work exactly like tooltip, but it shows how you can use portal.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class TooltipButton extends Component {
    state = {
        isHovered: false
    };

    buttonRef = React.createRef();

    onMouseOver = isOver => {
        this.setState({
            isHovered: isOver
        });
    };

    render() {
        const tooltip = (
            <div>
                {this.props.tooltip}
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    ref={this.buttonRef}
                    onMouseEnter={() => this.onMouseOver(true)}
                    onMouseLeave={() => this.onMouseOver(false)}
                >
                    {this.props.text}
                </button>
                {this.state.isHovered ?
                    ReactDOM.createPortal(tooltip, this.buttonRef.current) :
                    undefined}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

TooltipButton.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    tooltip: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default TooltipButton;
```

This example shows how to use portal, but the purpose of the portal is to add something (tooltip element) to the another element (document.body for example) not to the same element. It this case createPortal doesn't actually do anything.

It doesn't have any sense to open portal to the same room :)

I think you need to do something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class TooltipButton extends Component {
    state = {
        isHovered: false
    };

    buttonRef = React.createRef();

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.tooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
    }

    onMouseOver = isOver => {
        this.setState({
            isHovered: isOver
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.appendChild(this.tooltipElement);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.removeChild(this.el);
    }

    render() {
        let buttonRect;
        let tooltip;
        if (this.buttonRef.current) {
            buttonRect = this.buttonRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            tooltip = (
                <div style={{
                    zIndex: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: buttonRect.top,
                    left: buttonRect.right,
                    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
                }}>
                    {this.props.tooltip}
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    ref={this.buttonRef}
                    onMouseEnter={() => this.onMouseOver(true)}
                    onMouseLeave={() => this.onMouseOver(false)}
                >
                    {this.props.text}
                </button>
                {this.state.isHovered ?
                    ReactDOM.createPortal(tooltip, this.tooltipElement) :
                    undefined}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

TooltipButton.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    tooltip: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default TooltipButton;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise :) I guess my problem is, that making portal actually makes sense, because I use react-tether that adds the tethered component to the body, not as a child of targeted element.